# MongoDb $filter, then get distinct count

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working against a mongo collection that has the following schema

```
{ _id: "123", Items: [...] }
```

I current have a pipeline that goes through the collection and uses `$facet`ing to do some aggregation on the content of `Items`.

Here is what that looks like:

```
"myFacet": [
    "$project": {
       "_id": 1,
       "Name": 1,
       "totalCount": {
           "$size": {
                "$filter": { ... }
           }
       }

    }
]
```

What I am trying to do is do the same thing as `totalCount`, but one step further and just get a *distinct* count of the results.

I am aware of how I would do this in a normal aggregation by `$unwind`ing, then `$match`ing, and then `$group`.

But, I'm a little lost if I can do any further operations on the array in `$filter` that would give me some sort of distinct count. Before I go and refactor the entire query, I'd like to see if there's a way to accomplish it first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
"myFacet": [
    {"$project": {
       "_id": 1,
       "Name": 1,
       "data": {"$filter": { ... }}
      }
   },
   {"$project": {
       "_id": 1,
       "Name": 1,
       "totalCount": {$size:'$data'},
       "distinctCount": {$size: {$setIntersection: '$data'}}
   }}
]
```